# Python: replace email attachment

Tags: python, email-attachments

I am trying to replace the attachment in a received email with another file, directly on the mail server.
The email has a format like 
 `1518536813.M362147P20908.domain_name,S=4359863,W=4449393:2,RS`, if that is relevant.

I can parse that email and extract the attachment without any problem:

```
mail = '1518536813.M362147P20908.domain_name,S=4359863,W=4449393:2,RS'
with open(mail, 'rb') as f:
     msg = email.message_from_binary_file(f)
attachment = msg.get_payload()[1]
```

Now, I'm wondering whether I can strip that original attachment and add the new file (.xlsx) instead.
I've searched and tried some options but I confess that I have had no luck, while the documentation didn't really give me much insight.

There is a method `msg.set_payload()`but I'm not sure how to open that email file in write mode.

Is my objective achievable at all? Or do I need to generate another email with the new attachment and send it instead?

Comment: what mail protocol/server are  you using?

Comment: It's an IMAP server, Postfix if I'm correct.